# Python Magic Syntax

Tags: python, функции, override, декоратор

```py
def fib(n):
    return n if n < 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def wrap(n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]
    return wrap

fib = memo(fib)
```

**Правильно ли я все понял:**
в функцию `memo` мы передаем функцию `fib` которая рекурсивно вычисляет числа фибоначчи по n-параметру , на эту функцию указывает атрибут `f`, который и будет вызывать функцию `fib` в функции `wrap`.Далее мы переопределяем функцию `fib` функцией `wrap` и вот у меня вопрос , когда мы вызываем фукнцию `f(n) ( строка - cache[n] = f(n))`  у нас вызывается `fib` функция , а вот в этой функции у нас рекурсивно вызывается функция `wrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На английском SO [что-то подобное](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757871/decorating-recursive-functions-in-python) уже задавали.

Рассуждения верны. Попробую раскрыть.

`fib` в глобальном поле зрения заменяется на `wrap`. Внутри функции wrap мы вызываем оригинальную функцию `fib`, ссылка на которую хранится в локальной переменной `f`.

А вот внутри оригинальной функции, вызывая, `fib`, мы берем ссылку на нее уже из глобального поля зрения. А под `fib` у нас функция `wrap`.